# Updating a .docx file's page header using Apache POI

Tags: java, file, file-io, apache-poi, .doc

How can I update the page header of a `.docx` file using the Apache POI 3.7 API?

Comment: Please look my answer in this post [how-to-extract-header-data-from-docx-in-java-using-poi-3-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393505/how-to-extract-header-data-from-docx-in-java-using-poi-3-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, call [getHeaderFooterPolicy()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html#getHeaderFooterPolicy%28%29) on your XWPFDocument, which returns a [HeaderFooterPolicy](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/model/XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.html). From that, you can identify the appropriate header for your page (eg Default, First Page etc)

Once you have the appropriate [XWPFHeader](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFHeader.html) that you want to change, then you can go about editing it as any other document part. You can fetch the tables, the paragraphs etc, then remove them, add new ones, change the text of them etc. It's all the same process then as editing the main document.

Comment: can you provide some code examples that allows you to edit the header using the mentioned classes of POI?

Comment: Try looking at the unit tests, there are lots of examples given in there as part of testing that the feature works correctly

Comment: Additionally, the header works just like any other document part, so once you've learnt enough XWPF to be able to add / change paragraphs and tables, it's exactly the same process for the header

Comment: @Gagravarr Have you ever successfully changed a table cell with XWPF?

Answer (score 3):

Since your document is in `.docx` format, you'll need to use the XWPF component API of the POI project. You may find the `org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFHeader` class useful ([Javadoc](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFHeader.html)), but I've never used it myself.

I couldn't find a good reference for doing this with XWPF, but the following instructions describe accessing headers with HWPF, the analagous interface for older Word documents (AKA `.doc` docs):

> To get at the headers and footers of a Word document, first create a `org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument`. Next, you need to create a `org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.HeaderStores`, passing it your `HWPFDocument`. Finally, the `HeaderStores` gives you access to the headers and footers, including first / even / odd page ones if defined in your document. Additionally, `HeaderStores` provides a method for removing any macros in the text, which is helpful as many headers and footers do end up with macros in them.

The [page those instructions are from](http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/quick-guide.html) implies that header support was never that good in HWPF, let alone XWPF. For more bad news, [this other Apache page](http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/index.html) makes it sound like XWPF development has all but stalled. It's possible that what you want to do is planned but not supported yet.

Comment: The page you linked to only talks about HWPF development not being very active at the moment - most of the effort seems to be going into XWPF as that's where most people are interested

Comment: If you know anything about XWPF commits, then you know more than I do. However, that page does say "none of the [XWPF] committers are actively adding new features." @Gagravarr

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Writing Microsoft Word Documents in Java With Apache POI](http://tkgospodinov.com/writing-microsoft-word-documents-in-java-with-apache-poi/)

I never worked with Word file before, but done so with POI library for excel stuff, they are quite easy to follow  (they model the row, column, sheet etc for excel) so I am assuming they will be equally easy to do for Word files.

And do quick read on their guide [Apache POI - HWPF - Java API to Handle Microsoft Word Files](http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/index.html)

Comment: I was assuming the same when I started my project, I had so much success with spreadsheets why not use it for Word too? It has been an awful experience, definitely wouldn't recommend it unless you have a plain word doc. Every year when I have to update the Word docs the headers win every single time.