# Remove Header and Footer from .docx file

Tags: java, xwpf

Can we remove header and footer of .docx file? I'm using XWPFDocument. If anyone has idea, please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People who wants answer for this question, please refer the link
[How to replace placeholders in header of docx in java using poi 3.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393505/how-to-replace-placeholders-in-header-of-docx-in-java-using-poi-3-8)

Thanks!