# Remove header and Footer images of XWPFDocument java

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

I require to remove the header and footer images from .docx file by using java. I use XWPFDocument API. I dnt have any working code to show here. I'm able to remove the header texts by referring the link

[How to replace placeholders in header of docx in java using poi 3.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393505/how-to-replace-placeholders-in-header-of-docx-in-java-using-poi-3-8)

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: You can find something on Google to start with. Give a try and then ask here with some code.

Comment: The code which I tried is remove the texts in header by the link mentioned. I gave a search in google. There is no useful documentation on removing images from header and footer.